# use wavelet for improving spectral resolution

Tags: matlab, wavelet, superresolution

let us consider following code

```
function [sca_1,sca_2,sca_3,sca_4]=calc_wavelet(y,wname,scales,freq,fs)
%y-input signal
%wname-wavelet basis name
%freq-test frequencies
%fs-sampling rate
TAB_Sca2Frq = scal2frq(scales,wname,1/fs);
[~,idxSca_1] = min(abs(TAB_Sca2Frq-freq(1)));
sca_1 = scales(idxSca_1);
[mini,idxSca_2] = min(abs(TAB_Sca2Frq-freq(2)));
sca_2 = scales(idxSca_2);
[~,idxSca_3] = min(abs(TAB_Sca2Frq-freq(3)));
sca_3 = scales(idxSca_3);
[mini,idxSca_4] = min(abs(TAB_Sca2Frq-freq(4)));
sca_4 = scales(idxSca_4);
coefs = cwt(y,scales,wname);
clf; wscalogram('image',coefs,'scales',scales,'ydata',y);
hold on
plot([1 size(coefs,2)],[sca_1 sca_1],'Color','m','LineWidth',2);
plot([1 size(coefs,2)],[sca_2 sca_2],'Color','m','LineWidth',2);
plot([1 size(coefs,2)],[sca_3 sca_3],'Color','m','LineWidth',2);
plot([1 size(coefs,2)],[sca_4 sca_4],'Color','m','LineWidth',2);
```

i have  took following data

```
>> wname = 'morl';
scales = 1:1:128;
>> fs=100;
>> freq=[13.7   10.5    29.9    31
];
```

when i run following code

```
[scal_1,scal_2,scal_3,scal_4]=calc_wavelet(B,wname,scales,freq,fs);
```

got result :

[image]

one  frequency is lost,i have tried  also following  basis

```
>> wname = 'mexh';
>> wname = 'morl';
>> wname = 'haar';
>> wname = 'gaus4';
```

please  pay attention that  my model is following

https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/15559/understanding-1d-wavelet-analysis

so which wavelet basis should i choose for  good spectral  resolution?i want to use wavelet for ability to distinguish signals which are closed  spaced to each other,like in my case

freq=[13.7   10.5    29.9    31];

it could be  even more closed to each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The window shape chosen for your wavelet basis will generally only have a slight effect on frequency resolution.  To increase frequency resolution more, increase a scale factor that is related or proportional to the window length for a given frequency.  This will also decrease temporal resolution.

Comment: i have tried to increase scales,but it seems that wavelet also have  same problem of resolution  as  generally windows,,is it right?

Comment: in fact when we have unknow frequency components,it always  big question how big scales should i choose?as  it is related to AR model :How big model order should i choose

Comment: DFT windows have more problems with resolution than wavelet scale, but the problem they have in common are similar.

Comment: especially for   sinusoidal models in noise,so that means that there is not standard base or scales  related to  wavelet  to such models?